# C# Inconsistent accessibilty: return type is less accessible than method

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

I have a C# Application that is in decompiled form and contains some obfuscated properties and methods. I am getting error when building the project in VS 2012. The error says:

Error: Inconsistent accessibility: return type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator' is less accessible than method 'xf1555389a70c7d5a.x39b8e005139a3d89.xdd6080d77f5137d7.GetEnumerator()'

Here is my .cs code where error is shown:

```
public IEnumerator<x39b8e005139a3d89.xe657754b6d8c9c0b> GetEnumerator() // The Error is Shown at GetEnumerator() method
{
   throw new Exception("The method or operation is not implemented.");
}
```

The Class has 'public' Accessor.

What should I do to remove error?

Comment: Either `x39b8e005139a3d89` or `xe657754b6d8c9c0b` (or both) aren't public classes so you can't have a method returning an enumerator of them. You need to look at the class definition, not just the `GetEnumerator()` method.

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren Thanks for your comment. The errors were removed when I followed the steps that you given. `x39b8e005139a3d89` is Public class and `xe657754b6d8c9c0b` is an interface (private, not public). I changed it to public and errors were gone.